# HHVM 3.1 Stack Overflow

Tags: overflow, stack-overflow, fastcgi, hhvm

Running HHVM 3.1 using Ubuntu 14.04 Final Beta using Nginx with fastcgi.

Fatal error: Stack overflow in

I've tried increasing the stack using -vEval.VMStackElms=524288, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Any Ideas?

I checked the version it actually is **HHVM 3.0** I pull and built it from the 3.1 Tag.

`HipHop VM 3.0.0-dev (rel) Compiler: heads/HHVM-3.1-0-g3af5bc29494cedc3457f4d60f1afdd603337d08c Repo schema: 86fe165eb703fdba1680d5e43db3f5a3f836e504.`

I'm testing it with Magento. Wordpress seems to work just fine. Works fine with `php5-fpm`. It's failing when it's trying to load the magento config. `/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1407`

Comment: I got it working with an older hash.

https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/2290#issuecomment-39367134

Answer (score 1):

If any of your database connections are configured with `<use/>`, change that line you mentioned in Mage/Core/Model/Config.php from

`if (!empty($conn->use)) {`

to

`$use = (string)$conn->use;
if (!empty($use)) {`

The "right way" to do this is of course to make a copy of that class in your local code pool.

Comment: You are absolutely right. After digging much deeper I found out the <use /> was being pulled in from a custom etc/local.xml file. I didn't need it. I removed it and it worked fine. This way i didn't need to rewrite the file. The odd part is it worked fine with php5-fpm but failed to load with hhvm. I'm just glad it's working! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is nowhere near enough info. I also doubt you are using 3.1 since I didn't release it yet.

Try putting prints in you code to narrow down what function is being called recursively. Does the problem happen on php5?

Comment: Your right I checked the version it actually is HHVM 3.0 I pull and built it from the 3.1 Tag. HipHop VM 3.0.0-dev (rel)
Compiler: heads/HHVM-3.1-0-g3af5bc29494cedc3457f4d60f1afdd603337d08c
Repo schema: 86fe165eb703fdba1680d5e43db3f5a3f836e504. I'm testing it with Magento. Wordpress seems to work just fine. Works fine with php5-fpm. It's failing when it's trying to load the magento config. /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1407

Answer (score 0):

Remove < use /> in etc/local.xml fixed the problem.